# Porque estou a ter erro ao adicionar dois números usando apontadores?

Tags: c, ponteiro

```
#include <stdio.h>


int* adicionar(int *a,int *b)
{
    int c = *a + *b;
    return &c;
}



int main()
{
    int primeiro, segundo;
    int* temp;

    scanf("%d%d",&primeiro, &segundo);
    temp = adicionar(&primeiro, &segundo);

    printf("O resultado da soma é :%d",*t);
    return 0;
}
```

Estou a tentar adicionar dois números usando ponteiros, mas está a dar erro. O que estou fazer mal?

Comment: este programa nem compila...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int* adicionar(const int *a, const int *b)
{
    static int c = *a + *b;
    return &c;
}
```

O apontador está com um valor inválido porque estás a retornar um apontador com uma variável local. Assim a variável apontada não está ativa após sair do método.